# OpenERP - Passing domain from button -> action -> search view

Tags: odoo

I have a button as follows:

```
<button string="View Cancelled Applications" name="%(action_recruit_application)d" type="action" domain="[('state','=','cancel')]"/>
```

The action is as follows:

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_recruit_application">
    <field name="name">Applications</field>
    <field name="res_model">recruit.application</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_recruit_application_search"/>
   </record>
```

Finally the search view is as follows:

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_recruit_application_search">
    <field name="name">recruit.application.search</field>
    <field name="model">recruit.application</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Applications">
            <field name="application_id"/>
            <field name="name"/>     
            <field name="application_date"/>
            <field name="state"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

I can't seem to pass the 'state' = 'cancel' to the search view.

Could anyone please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please clarify the question?

Comment: @Jayram, clicking on the Button should automatically filter the search view where state = cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding context in the button.For example

```
<button string="View Cancelled Applications" name="%(action_recruit_application)d" type="action" domain="[('state','=','cancel')]" context="{'search_default_state':'cancel'}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Anoma, tks for your reply.  I've tried, it doesn't work.  I figure it's something to do with adding a domain to the action and search view as well.